# How to prove conditional expectation?

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation, conditional-expectation

How to proof that if $E(X\mid F)$ is measurable with respect to $F$ then there exists $y=E(X\mid F)$ such that $(y>a)\in F$, $\forall a\in R$?

Comment: I think you may need to rephrase/expand the question.  The definition of the conditional expectation $E[X \mid F]$ includes that it is $F$-measurable.  Hence, by the definition of being $F$-measurable
$\{ \omega \mid E[X \mid F] > a \} \in F$ for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @RyanSullivant, What I am asking is basically why is it that because $E[X|F]$ is $F$-measurable then $\{ω∣E[X∣F]>a\}∈F$ for any $a∈R$. Is there a proof?

Comment: Because that's exactly the definition of being $F$-measurable.

Comment: @RyanSullivant, Is there a text or a link that explains this. That would really help.

Comment: What definition of $F$-measurability do you know?  It can be found in any book or set of notes on probability. For example, see definition 1.2.1 and the paragraph after exercise 1.2.11 here
http://statweb.stanford.edu/~adembo/stat-310a/lnotes.pdf

Comment: @RyanSullivant, I was asked to proof this as part of something like a quiz so I am not sure that my answer can be just because this is the definition of measurability of $F$.